# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const mynamespace::mytype*' to 'const T*'

Tags: c++, casting

I have these two cpp file.
When I try to coding a template function `Method()`, the C2440 error occurs.

I tried three different way to do the assignment. Only the C-style cast can pass the compiler.

I want to know how to do that in C++-style.

Thanks : )

```
FileA:

template <typename T>
int ClassName<T>::Method(params...)
{
    const T* temp = (T*)GetValueArray(); // C-style cast, right √
    const T* temp = GetValueArray(); // no cast, error C2440
    const T* temp = static_cast<T*>(GetValueArray()); // error C2440, reinterpret or 
                                                      // const or dynamic_cast all C2440 
}

_______________

FileB:

typedef double mytype;

const mynamespace::mytype* GetValueArray() const
{
    mynamespace::mytype res[3] = {1,2,3};
    return res;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

typedef double MyType;

const MyType* GetValueArray()
{
    MyType* ptr = new MyType;
    *ptr = 20.20;
    return ptr;
}

template <typename T>
void Method()
{
    const T* temp = (T*)GetValueArray(); // C-style cast, right √
    //const T* temp = GetValueArray(); // no cast, error C2440
    //const T* temp = static_cast<T*>(GetValueArray()); // error C2440, reinterpret or 
                                                      // const or dynamic_cast all C2440
    std::cout << *temp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Method<double>();
}
```

I get the output 20.2. Here I can get the right result, because `T` is just `double`. In this situation, with lost `const`, the program can pass the compiler.

But if I change to `Method<int>`, no matter what the result is (actually the result is useless number), but why C2440 will occur?

Comment: @CoryKramer Oops, still C2440, and the content is the same. `from 'const mynamespace::mytype *' to 'const T *'`. But still thank you.

Comment: By the way, `GetValueArray()` returns a pointer to an array that is now out of scope after returning from your function, so your code will have a dangling pointer.

Comment: @CoryKramer Uh, that's only a simplification of my code, I just want to show that I returned a `mytype` pointer. The key problem is in `Method()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cast lost the const-ness

```
const T* temp = static_cast<const T*>(GetValueArray());
```

The reason the C-style cast works is the [one of the casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) it tries is a `const_cast` which is likely not what you want in this case.

Comment: OP's (incomplete) code mentions `const_cast`, so that's probably even a `static_cast` + `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` + `const_cast`.

Comment: But my program get the result I expected (maybe coincidence, but right) with C-style cast, while totally cannot compile with C++ cast.

Comment: Can you show an example of trying to call `ClassName<T>::Method`? Like a small example in `main`?